# Can we say that there exist an integer $n$ such $A+nB$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

If $A$ and $B$ are $3\times 3$ matrices and $A$ is invertible, then can we say that there exists an integer $n$ such that $A+nB$ invertible?

I was trying to show this by choosing $n$ such that eignevalues of $A+nB$ are non-zero. In the case where $B = I$ we can find the eigenvalues of $A+nB$ that would be $\lambda + nB$ (though I am not certain about its proof). This choosing of $n$ such that $\lambda$ is not equal to $-n$ times an eigenvalue of $B$ will serve the purpose. But I am not sure about general $B$. What if I take arbitrary matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Hint: $p(n) := \det(A + nB)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 3$ in $n$, which isn't zero as $p(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: If $-n$ is not an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}B$ then $I+nA^{-1}B$ is invertible so $A+nB$ is also invertible.

Comment: @martini is it a polynomial of degree 3 or $\leq 3$?

Comment: still i haven't got a complete answer. I need little more help.

Comment: Isn't the (trivial) answer to this question that yes, for the integer $n=0$, $A+nB$ is invertible, since it's just $A$, which is invertible by hypothesis?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since $\det(A+xB)$ is a polynomial in $x$, it either has finitely many zeroes or is $0$ for all $x$. Since $A$ is invertible it is not zero when $x=0$, thus all but finitely many integers $n$ are such that $\det(A+nB)\neq 0$ so $A+nB$ is invertible.

Comment: I need explanation for $\det(A+xB)$ has finitely many zeros or is 0 for all $x$.

Comment: It's a polynomial (when $A$,$B$ are $3\times 3$ it has degree $3$). All nonzero polynomials have only finitely many zeroes (in fact, no more than their degree).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204880/is-it-true-there-exists-a-non-zero-integer-such-that-a-nb-is-invertible-for

Comment: And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406585/is-anb-invertible-when-a-is-invertible