# Is it true, there exists a non-zero integer such that $A + nB$ is invertible for $A$ is invertible and $B$ is general $3 \times 3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are any $3 \times 3$ matrices and 
A is any invertible matrix, then there exist an integer $n$
such that $A + nB$ is invertible.

It is easy to check if we take $n = 0$, then the result always holds, But I want to know, when $n$ is non-zero then the result is true or not.

Comment: Why did you accept an incomplete solution?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406585/is-anb-invertible-when-a-is-invertible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the determinant of $A+nB$ can be written as a polynomial $f$ in $n$ of degree 3. There are at most 3 real roots of $f$ and any integer $m$ which is not a root gives $A+mB$ which has non-zero determinant, and so invertible.

Comment: The coefficient of n^3 in det(A+nB) is det(B) hence, if B is not invertible, the degree of det(A+nB) is **not** 3.

Comment: You need to assume something on $B$ so that your polynomial is not identically zero though. I don't know what one needs to assume. It would probably have to do with the rank of $A$ and/or $B$.

Comment: The degree of $P(X) = \det(A+XB)$ is indeed the rank of $B$. But we know $P(0) \ne 0$, so $P$ is not identically zero, and there exist $n \ne 0$ such that $P(n) \ne 0$ (because a polynomial of any degree can only have finitely many zeros).

Comment: @JoelCohen **This** is a proof.