# Is $A+nB$ invertible when $A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$  and  $B$  are  given $3\times 3$ matrices where  $A$  is  invertible . Then  does  there  exist  an  integer  $n$  such  that  $A+nB$  is invertible ?

Now  I  do  not  have  any  clue  on  this  like sum  of  two  matrices , how  to  find  if  invertible  or  not  even  if  both  were  given  to  be  invertible?Trivially  $0$  is  a  possible  value  of  $n$  but  what  about  the  non-zero  values , if  any?

Comment: A possible direction: For $C_n=A+nB$ to be invertible, you need it's columns to be linearily independent (they need to be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$). So, it's basically a problem in proving that you can't have all sets of rows of all $C_n$s all linearily dependent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression for the determinant is a cubic in $n$. It can therefore be zero in at most three places, or everywhere. The latter occurs iff the polynomial is the zero polynomial. The constant term of this polynomial is $\text{det}(A)$ - exercise - so is nonzero. Therefore, for all but at most three $n$, $A + n B$ is invertible.

Comment: I don't know how else to describe it. $\text{det}(A+nB)$ is a polynomial of degree 3 where $n$ is the variable. (This is very standard terminology in English maths.)

Answer (score 11):

Here is an easier solution without using determinants:
Suppose $\lambda$ is a nonzero number. Then
$$
A + \lambda B = \lambda( \tfrac{1}{\lambda} I + BA^{-1})A.
$$
Thus $A + \lambda B$ is not invertible if and only if
$\tfrac{1}{\lambda} I + BA^{-1}$ is not invertible (because our hypothesis is that $A$ is invertible), which happens if and only if $-\tfrac{1}{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $BA^{-1}$. However, $BA^{-1}$ has at most 3 eigenvalues (because we are dealing with $3 \times 3$ matrices). Thus
$A + \lambda B$ in invertible for all but at most 3 values of $\lambda$.